# Maven execution of single attached test

Tags: maven, testing

I'm relatively new to maven and have been struggling with attached tests, I've found a few articles here that have got me part of the way there but can't quite get that last little bit.  Here is what I'm trying to do.  I have 2 modules one that defines a set of interfaces and rudimentary test of those interfaces.  The second module provides an implementation of the interface and I'd like to run the predefined test on it.  I boiled it down to a simple example, here are the two projects:

```
interface
 + pom.xml
 + src
    + main
       + java
          + demo
             + Messenger.java
    + test
       + java
          + demo
             + MessengerTest.java

impl
 + pom.xml
 + src
    + main
       + java
          + demo
             + impl
                + MessengerImpl.java
    + test
       + resources
          + context.xml
```

The interface pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd">
  <groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>interface</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The Messenger.java source:

```
package demo;

public interface Messenger {
    String getMessage();
}
```

The MessengerTest.java source:

```
package demo;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import demo.Messenger;

public class MessengerTest {
    private BeanFactory beanfactory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        beanfactory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public final void testGetMessage() throws Exception {
        final Messenger msngr = beanfactory.getBean(Messenger.class);
        String msg = msngr.getMessage();
        assertNotNull(msg);
        assertTrue(msg.length() > 0);
    }
}
```

Executing 'mvn install' appears to do the right thing creating interface-1.0.jar and interface-1.0-tests.jar in my local repository.

The implementation code is simple, the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>impl</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>interface</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>interface</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

The MessageImpl.java source:

```
package demo.impl;

import demo.Messenger;

public class MessengerImpl implements Messenger {

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And finally, the spring context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
  <bean id="MyMessenger" class="demo.impl.MessengerImpl"/>
</beans>
```

With all of this in place I execute 'mvn -Dtest=demo.MessengerTest test', and unfortunately it fails with "... No tests were executed!".  So there is the problem.

Sorry, for being so long winded but I wanted to be fairly complete, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have `<skipTests>true</skipTests>` set in the maven-surefire plugin:  Could that be the problem?

Comment: I believe that only impacts the building of the interface artifacts, there are no implementation classes so the test can't be run prior to install.

Comment: I confirmed this, I removed it from the pm and reinstalled (specifying -Dtest.skip=true on the command line) and I get the same results.

Comment: According to the surefire documentation, if you set test.skip=true,  the *Test.java files aren't even compiled - ergo, no Test.class files would exist in your .m2 cache after building the first project.  ( http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html ).  This doesn't explain why your tests didn't run when just <skipTests> was set to true though, so you probably still have a problem.

Comment: True.  My mistake, repeated with -DskipTests=true, verified the test class was in the test jar.  And yes the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

Surefire doesn't scan through the classpath when deciding what classes to run, so only tests defined in the same module are normally considered. It checks in `target/classes` in the `impl` project, doesn't see any tests, and ignores `MessengerTest`. You could define a test suite in the `impl` project that references the tests to run, or unzip the dependency into `target/classes`.

Comment: I've tested using a test suite that includes tests from the interface module and this does work, this is my fall back position.  Thanks.